# Toggle all Angular checkboxes in a group

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a table of text-checkbox items, each with a description and a checkbox. I now need to add an uber-checkbox that will either clear or check all boxes. The current code, is shown below, with my first attempt at a solution highlighted.

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="table table-bordered">            
     <tr id="myBlusteringAttempt">  
        <td width="90%">
            <p>Clear/Check all options</p>
        </td>
        <td width="10%" align="center" valign="middle">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-change="toggleCheckboxes()">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="existing-code-that-works" ng-repeat="declaration in LegalDeclaration.ReplacementOfPolicy.ReplacementPolicyDeclarations">
        <td width="90%">
            <p>{{declaration.DeclarationText}}</p>
        </td>
        <td width="10%" align="center" valign="middle">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="declaration.AcceptDeclaration">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I could probably so easily do this with jQuery, but I'd rather use Angular's jQuery facade, and let there be no miscegenation of frameworks.

Comment: is the `declaration.AcceptDeclaration` of ng-repeat going to be toggle from `toggleCheckboxes`  method?

Comment: @pankajparkar Either from that method, or what ever way I find that works, with the help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first you need to setup an `ng-model` to the toggle checkbox in order to make this thing work, or else Angular may probably [complain](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/ctreq?p0=ngModel&p1=ngChange):

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="toggle" ng-change="toggleCheckboxes()">
```

Afterwards, you should loop your results and bind them with the checkbox value:

```
    $scope.toggle = false;
    $scope.toggleCheckboxes = function () {
        angular.forEach($scope.LegalDeclaration.ReplacementOfPolicy.ReplacementPolicyDeclarations, function (value, key) {
            value.AcceptDeclaration = $scope.toggle;
        });
    }
```

[Full working example](https://jsfiddle.net/pbcnqmzg/embedded/result/)

[The code of the example above](http://jsfiddle.net/pbcnqmzg/)

> Edited
>   I should notice that your approach of toggling UI elements as checkboxes is different to Angular's scope. Angular mostly is used as a databound MV* framework, fetching data into your view. You should read more about using Angular (or any other MV* framework like Backbone ) : ["Thinking in AngularJS" if I have a jQuery background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background)

Comment: Yes, thanks, I actually didn't want to toggle the checkboxes together but the models bound to them. For strange reasons grouping by checkbox vs by model seems better.

Answer (score 1):

In `toggleCheckboxes`, you just need to set all the models to the value you want.

```
var currentAllStatus = false;
$scope.toggleCheckboxes = function () {
    currentAllStatus = !currentAllStatus;
    $scope.LegalDeclaration.ReplacementOfPolicy.ReplacementPolicyDeclarations.forEach(function (declaration) {
        declaration.AcceptDeclaration = currentAllStatus;
    });
};
```